# Store GPS information in database

Tags: database, postgresql, mongodb

I need to continuously collect the location details of our users (say around 100K, at a frequency of 10 sec). What I am interested in is list of users near a particular location (i.e., I don't usually need the complete path followed, most SO questions are related to tracking)

In general what is a good database for write heavy applications, where all I need is latest match for the query (not the entire result set). I am thinking of deleting the records older than 1 day and storing in separate table for faster fetches. Are there any better alternatives?

What is ideal way to design such schema? I am thinking either PostGIS or MongoDB to store this info. Are there any other better alternatives or combination of tools?

Additonal Info: Main app is written in django

Any references, links are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> In general what is a good database for write heavy applications, where all I need is latest match for the query (not the entire result set). I am thinking of deleting the records older than 1 day and storing in separate table for faster fetches. Are there any better alternatives?

PostGIS is great. If you're using any GIS functionality, PostGIS is easily the best offering in the FOSS world.